# SQL Server Collation to Match SSIS Ordering

Tags: sql-server, sorting, ssis, collation, sql-server-2019

Example values from a SQL Server data set as they appear after an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
X0000000-2009
X000000-1-2010
X0000001-2010
```

If I use `ORDER BY Field COLLATE Latin1_General_bin` they come out slightly differently as:

```
X000000-1-2010
X0000000-2009
X0000001-2010
```

I'm looking to use this data in a Merge Join transformation in SSIS without the need for a Sort transformation, however, a Sort transformation will order them as:

```
X0000000-2009
X0000001-2010
X000000-1-2010
```

This is problematic because I need to match the SSIS ordering in my SQL source query in order for the Merge Join to work properly.

Is there a collation I can use in my `ORDER BY` that is guaranteed to match the SSIS ordering?

Comment: Not sure on your specific case. If not, I have had to do the ugly and sort both sources within the package to ensure they get the same sort order. However, if you expect at most 1 row from your merge join, a Lookup will probably provide better performance and not require the data be sorted

Comment: Seems it looks like this article from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/sort-data-for-the-merge-and-merge-join-transformations?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15 Not sure if it is helpful, but hope